# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal constructor at new SvelteElement (index.mjs:1381)

Tags: custom-element, rollup, svelte, rollupjs, sapper

> Uncaught promise when registering a custom element using the latest
>   sapper, svelte, nodeJS, and rollup stack using the following
>   statements.

**REPL example**: https://svelte.dev/repl/489ee8acd10848b0bb1feb2535bd6cc5?version=3.16.5 created locally

```
<svelte:options tag="parlax-background" />
    & rollup.config.js
    export default {
    client: {
    input: config.client.input(),
    output: config.client.output(),
    plugins: [
    replace({...})
    svelte({
    dev: !production,
    customElement: true,
    // and tried also with customElement: { tag: "my-element"}
    hydratable: true,
    emitCss: true
```

**I want to mention that I had tested on a fresh project**

**Logs**

```
[Client Side]
    => Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at new SvelteElement (index.mjs:1381)
    [Server Side]
    => The 'tag' option is used when generating a custom element. Did you forget the 'customElement: true' compile option?
    44: <svelte:options tag="my-element" />
```

**1. When I registering  [ **`customElement: true`** ] in the config i get**

**2. If I do not register my element in the config I do not get any error, but neither my element is registered**  :(

**Ref:** https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4132

Answer (score 11):

As described in the referenced [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4132), once you configure the Svelte compiler with `customElements: true`, you're expected to provide an element tag for **all** your components (using `<svelte:options tag="my-component"/>`.

In your REPL's example, this would mean updating `App.svelte` with e.g. `<svelte:options tag="my-app"/>`

When you now run the app, you should not see the error in the console anymore, but a working app.

Comment: What about third party libraries?

Comment: Fixed it, I am building a web components library and did not have the options tag in my App, only in the individual components. Thanks.